# Using two SELECT statements in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

I have two tables, one is 'points' which contains ID and points. The other table is 'name' and contains ID, Forename, and Surname.

I'm trying to search for the total number of points someone with the forename Anne, and surname Brown, scored.

Would I have to do a join? If so, is this correct?

```
SELECT Name.Forename, Name.Surname
    FROM Name
    FULL OUTER JOIN Points
    ON Name.ID=Points.ID
    ORDER BY Name.Forename;
```

But then I also have to add the points, so would I have to use:

```
SELECT SUM (`points`) FROM Points
```

Then there is also the WHERE statement so that it only searches for the person with this name:

```
WHERE `Forename`="Anne" OR `Surname`="Brown";
```

So how does this all come together (based on the assumption that you do something like this)?

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT Name.ID, Forename, Surname, SUM(Points)
FROM Name
INNER JOIN Points ON Name.ID = Points.ID
/* Optional WHERE clause:
WHERE Name.ForeName = 'Anne' AND Name.Surname='Brown'
*/
GROUP BY Name.ID, Name.Forename, Name.Surname
```

Answer (score 1):

So, first, your answer:

```
select sum(points) as Points
from
Points
inner join Name on Name.ID = Points.ID
where
Name.Forename ='Anne' and Name.SurName='Brown'
```

Secondly, FULL JOINS are bad since they pull all values from both sets even those without matches. If you want to only return values that match your criteria (A & B) you must use an INNER JOIN.

Thirdly, here is the [MySQL reference documentation on SQL statement syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax.html). Please consider reading up on it and familiarizing yourself at least with the basics like JOINs, aggregation (including GROUP BY and HAVING), WHERE clauses, UNIONs, some of the basic functions provided, and perhaps subqueries. Having a good base in those will get you 99% of the way through most MySQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this with a subquery.

```
SELECT Name.Forename, Name.Surname, Name.ID,
(SELECT SUM (`points`) FROM Points where Points.ID = Name.ID) as total_points
    FROM Name ORDER BY Name.Forename;
```

However, I would like to point out, that it appears that your linking of the tables is incorrect.  I can not be completely sure without seeing the tables, but I imagine it should be where points.userid = name.id